# Modal created with livewire-ui/modal doesn't close

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I am checking the `livewire-ui/modal` as described in [this github page](https://github.com/livewire-ui/modal.)

The modal is showing properly when the open button is clicked but it **never closes** whatever the mean used is, e.g. :

- clicking away
- using the escape touch
- using a close button with this code

```
<button wire:click="$emit('closeModal')">No, do not delete</button>
```

- usinge a close button with this code

```
<button class="button-link" wire:click.prevent="close()"> Poster</button>
```

and having the close function in the modal like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use LivewireUI\Modal\ModalComponent;

class Hello extends ModalComponent
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.hello');
    }

    public function close(){
        
        $this->closeModal();
    }
}
```

Comment: does the browser console report any error ?

Answer (score 1):

The functioning was due to the fact that I had 2 alpine in the page
One as directly in the page (CDN) and the other inside app.js (require 'alpinejs'). I just kept require 'alpinejs' and now it works.

Comment: Thank you, this is a working solution for me. I was using 2 different versions of AlphineJS and now I only use the newest version.